# having an error while building my apk

Tags: java, android

Here is my grade.build file And this is error:

> Error:Execution failed for task
>   ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
>
> > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry:
> >     com/google/android/gms/common/api/zza.class

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {`

compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "26.0.0"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "romasakhalid.css"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled true
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

}
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
}
buildTypes {

    release {

        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }

}

dexOptions 
{
preDexLibraries = false
 }
}
dependencies {`

compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'

    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
})

compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.0.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.0.0'
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:0.6.2'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'


testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably using the wrong version of `firebase-ui-database`. According to the [github page](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android) it has fixed dependencies on the `com.google.firebase` versions. This means you have to be sure that `com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:0.6.2` supports `com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.0.0`.

You can check it with the gradle dependency tree or you use one of the pre defined suggestions from the developer e.g.

FirebaseUI Version  Firebase/Play Services Version
2.2.0   11.0.4
2.1.1   11.0.2
2.0.1   11.0.1
1.2.0   10.2.0
1.1.1   10.0.0 or 10.0.1
1.0.1   10.0.0 or 10.0.1
1.0.0   9.8.0

Comment: Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.
> Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin (information about the latest version is available at https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/) or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 9.0.0.